# Where to add activity indicator view?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I have two view controllers - I will simply call them A and B to help you understand with ease.

A view controller has a button linked to B by storyboard (not manually coded). And, B view controller retrieves bunch of json data from DB server in viewDidLoad method.  Because retrieving json data takes some time, I need to add a activity indicator to let users know it's doing something - not frozen. However, I'm not quite sure where I should add the activity indicator view.

If you were in my shoes, where would you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a blocking call in viewDidLoad that will cause the UI to freeze on A before moving to B so I would suggest adding the Activity Indicator on A. Although you may notice that because of the blocking call to the DB, your UI changes immediately before the blocking call also get frozen and you won't see any UI change.

The way I usually handle this is by spawning a new thread for the blocking call thus freeing up the main thread for UI and then adding an Activity Indicator where necessary (on A or B depends on design but I would recommend showing it on B in this case from a usability POV).

Just to avoid the hassle of managing all this on my own, I usually end up using something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) or a similar library which are much easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer & suggestion. Your answer described what the problem of my app and solutions were clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the normal interface builder to position it where you would like it to be seen, and set the `hidesWhenStopped` variable to `YES` so that it isn't visible after you've finished getting your data. Then just tell it to stop in your JSON callback.

In terms of design, the 'done thing' is to put it in the middle of whatever is being loaded. For an image, this would be the middle of where the image will be shown. For a table you might go for a large activity indicator in the middle of the screen, or on an empty 'placeholder' cell. Think about where the user's eye will travel to try and see the data they want, and that's where they should see the indicator.

Comment: So... I wanna display the indicator before the B view controller is loaded. Does that mean I gotta do that in A view controller? If so, in which method should I write the codes in? cuz the button is linked by Storyboard, I have no customized method or stuff :/

Comment: Sorry I've never used the Storyboard but, from my experience, the best thing to do is make sure that view controller B is loaded as fast as possible (i.e. before the data comes in) and have the activity indicator spinning on there until you receive the data. Without going into specifics, this will probably involve view controller B making the request in the first place (so that it can handle the callback) and therefore A will supply whatever information B needs to make that request.

Comment: Now I got the concept.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an alert view with a message in the title then you add a sub view to the alert which is the activity indicator.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Doing something\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[alertView show];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alertView.bounds.size.width / 2, alertView.bounds.size.height - 50);
[alertView addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];
```

later on in code dismiss...

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Interesting combination of views :)  Should I do that in A view controller to let people know the next page is being loaded?

Comment: Sorry if I am not understanding your issue but it looks like to me in the viewdidload in b is where you code is that does lookup and if so I would agree with other suggestion that you put that in an another thred to free up main ui thread. I would then add this code before that thread. Then after you thread you can use a selector to call a method that can remove this view.